# extjs 4 same component multiple tabs

Tags: tabs, extjs4

i m working with extjs 4 & rails 3. i am having toolbar & tab panel. i want to use same toolbar in all the tab panel & want buttons on the toolbar to work according to tab that is active. For eg. toolbar contains add,edit,etc buttons. Suppose i have region & category tabs. When region tab is active i should be able to perform "ADD" operation for "Region" & so on. What can be the correct way to achieve this in extjs 4 ? I am not able to assign action on toolbar in Region & Category controllers?
i referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034975/using-same-item-in-multiple-tab-in-extjs)but no idea as to how can i implement it in my code ? 
Here is sample code of "Regions" extjs mvc controller that i have tried. The problem is if i write similar code in **Category** contoller for ADD btn of commontoolbar, ADD implementation of **Region** gets called :(

```
    Ext.define('overdrive.controller.Regions', {
        extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
        views: [
            'region.RegionList',
            'region.RegionForm',
            'region.RegionPanel',
            'common.CommonToolbar'
        ],
        models: ['Region'],
        stores: ['Regions'],
         init: function() {
            this.control({
                'viewport > panel': {
                    render: this.onPanelRendered
                },
                'regionpanel':{
                    beforerender:this.addToolbar
                } ,
                'commontoolbar button[action=chk]': {
                    click: this.chk
                }

            });
        },
        chk:function()
        {

            var tabcon = Ext.getCmp('tabcon');//tabcon is id of tab panel
             var activetab = tabcon.getActiveTab();

             var activetabid = activetab.getId();
             console.log('Active Tab ID:'+activetabid);
                if(activetabid == 'regiontab'){
                alert('Clicked button in region Tab');
                }else if(activetabid == 'storetab'){
                 alert('Clicked button in store Tab');
                }
        },


       addToolbar:function()
       {

            var regionpanel=Ext.widget('regionpanel');
            var regiontab=Ext.getCmp('regiontab');
            var tabcon = Ext.getCmp('tabcon');


           regiontab.add({
                xtype:'commontoolbar', id:'regiontoolbar',
                itemId: 'regiontoolbar'
           });

        },

       addRegion: function(button) {

            var regiontoolbar=button.up('regiontoolbar');
            var regiontab = Ext.getCmp('regiontab');
            var regionpanel = regiontab.down('regionpanel');
            var regionform = regionpanel.down('regionform');
            regiontoolbar.child('#add').setDisabled(true);
            regiontoolbar.child('#edit').setDisabled(true);
            regiontoolbar.child('#delete').setDisabled(true);
            regiontoolbar.child('#save').setDisabled(false);
            regiontoolbar.child('#cancel').setDisabled(false);
            regionpanel.layout.setActiveItem(regionform);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope the following code will help you:

```
btn = {
    id: 'button',
    width : 130,
    height : 35,
    text: 'Button',
    listeners : {
        click : function(){
         var activetab = Ext.getCmp('extabs').getActiveTab();
         var activetabid = activetab.getId();
            if(activetabid == 'regiontab'){
            alert('Clicked button in region Tab');
            }else if(activetabid == 'countrytab'){
             alert('Clicked button in country Tab');
            }
        }
    }
};
toolbar = Ext.create('Ext.Toolbar',{
    id:'extoolbar',
    width : 350,
    height : 40
});
country = {
    id : 'countrytab',
    title : 'Country'
};
region = {
    id : 'regiontab',
    title : 'Region'
};
var exTabs = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel',{
    id : 'extabs',
    activeTab : 0,
    width : 350,
    plain : true,
    style : 'background:none',
    items : [region,country],
    listeners : {
        beforerender : function(){
         Ext.getCmp('regiontab').add(toolbar);
            toolbar.add(btn);
        },
        tabchange : function(tp,newTab,currentTab){
            if(newTab.getId()=='countrytab'){
                toolbar.removeAll();
             Ext.getCmp('countrytab').add(toolbar);
                toolbar.add(btn);
            }
            if(newTab.getId()=='regiontab'){
                toolbar.removeAll();
             Ext.getCmp('regiontab').add(toolbar);
                toolbar.add(btn);

            }
        }
    }
});
exWindow = Ext.create('Ext.Window',{
    id : 'examplewin',
    title : 'tabs sample',
    layout : 'fit',
    width : 350,
    height : 300,
    draggable : false,
    resizable : false,
    plain : true,
    frame : false,
    shadow : false,
    items : [exTabs]
}).show();
```

You can check the working sample of above code by clicking the following link:

http://jsfiddle.net/kVbra/23/

1.After opening the above link you can find the result in right bottom corner.
2.As per your question one toolbar is created and it is using in two tabs with same button.
3.If you click on the button,then it will get the current tab id and it will display the different result as based on which tab is activated.

Comment: hey thnx @kiran thats a helpful code, but in dis u r adding 2 diff buttons to the tabs but i want "same" buttons on toolbar to act differently depending upon active tab. I mean smthing like adding button btn1 to toolbar n shud alert "region" on region tab & same for country.

Comment: @Shruti you can check now.I changed the code as per your requirement.you can check working,by clicking on the changed working sample.

Comment: thnx a lot for such fast reply,that is what i wanted but the problem is i m using extjs 4 mvc pattern. So i have seperate controller for country & region. How can i do same on controller, bcoz if i refer toolbar through its alias then it does not act according to active tab. Is there a way to identify same toolbar with different id in controllers?

Comment: thnx i tried ur code it works fine. now is there a way to redirect control to particular extjs controller depending upon active tab in extjs mvc since i have  defined everything in controller ??

Comment: Can you share that code with us?We will try to find the solution. :-)

Comment: i have edited my ques & posted sample code that i have been working on. i want a way to give unique identification to toolbar in every controller/tab & then attach action on it in seperate controller using that identity?

Comment: If you define the components globally you can use the component or the component id every where.But here i didnt get you about unique identification for toolbar means?

Comment: i mean i m defining actions on toolbar with same name i.e. commontoolbar as a result actions that are defined for it in region controller are available in country controller also. If i follow your approach i will have to check for all the tabs that exist in my proj. So can i restrict scope of commontoolbar  to particular controller may b by using unique name for it ?

Comment: I dnt knw whether im thinkin in right dir or not, but can i create different instances/objects for commontoolbar & then override method for it? i m lil weak in extjs 4 :(

Comment: As per i know,if you are in region tab(active) then you need to get the details from region controller and get the actions as per above code.If you are in country tab then go to country controller and read the actions.

Comment: My advise is it is better to use unique id's.Because if region tab is in active position then you can directly call that particular action basedon unique id.If you are in coutry then it is also easy with unique id.

Comment: when i add commontoolbar to tab, i m assigning unique id for commontoolbar for that tab. how can i bind actions in every controller using that unique id of commontoolbar?  As in my code that i have posted i m assigning actions using xtype:commontoolbar how can i do it for "id" of commontoolbar?

Comment: Check thwe above code like if region tab is active then you need to add the buttons under region controller.Next buttonclick event you need to check active tab id and then assign controller i mean actin to that particular button

Answer (score 1):

If you are strict to use only one class,may be the below code also helpful for you shruti:

```
Ext.define('Sample', {    
    alternateClassName: ['Example', 'Important'],     
    code: function(msg) {        
        alert('Sample for alternateClassName... ' + msg);     
    },
    renderTo :document.body
});
var hi = Ext.create('Sample');
hi.code('Sample');
var hello = Ext.create('Example');
hello.code('Example');
var imp = Ext.create('Important');
imp.code('Important');
```

Working sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/kesamkiran/kVbra/30/